Creating AWS Glue tables as metadata mapping layer for DynamoDB items without using Athena connector
Problem Description: I need to create a metadata mapping layer in AWS Glue for DynamoDB items without crawling the entire table. The goal is to enable querying DynamoDB through Athena while not knowing item attributes in advance.
Requirements:

Two Glue tables: one for item_type DDB Item metadata, one for actual item_type_item
Item Must map DynamoDB items' structure without
exporting/crawling entire table
Should enable Athena queries using
this metadata

What I've Tried:

Creating Glue tables with boto3:
 client.create_table(
         DatabaseName=database,
         TableInput={
             "Name": table_name,
             "StorageDescriptor": {
                 "Location": "my_ddb_table", 
                 "Columns": columns,
             },
             "TableType": "EXTERNAL_TABLE",
             "Parameters": {
                 "classification": "dynamodb",
                 "typeOfData": "table",
                 "rangeKey": "sk", 
                 "hashKey": "pk"
             },
         },
     )



Athena queries return: Error: HIVE_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT: Unable to create input format
I even tried passing
"StorageDescriptor": {  
          "Columns": {} 
          "Location": f"arn:aws:dynamodb:{region}:{account_id}:table/{dynamodb_table}"
}

And this:
"StorageDescriptor": {
          "Location": dynamodb_table,
          "InputFormat": "com.amazonaws.glue.dynamodb.hive.DynamoDBInputFormat",
          "OutputFormat": "com.amazonaws.glue.dynamodb.hive.DynamoDBOutputFormat",
}

Tables are associated with Glue Database but not available for queries in Athena.

Tried using Glue crawler:


Crawls entire DynamoDB table
Problem: Returns all items without distinguishing between item_type and actual items
Cannot pre-define attribute structure

Question: Is it possible to create Glue tables that map DynamoDB item structures without:

Using the Athena DynamoDB connector
Crawling the entire table
Exporting data to S3

The Athena connector would be used later for actual queries, but first I need this metadata mapping layer. How can I achieve this?
Technical Context:

Using AWS Lambda with boto3
DynamoDB table uses single-table design
Need to maintain mapping between item_type definition and actual items of item_type stored in DynamoDB.


You have a single table with two different entities, that you want to break into two separate Glue tables?

Yes, <item_type> entity storing schema of <item_type>_items. Since the schema will be unknown when rnning Athena queires I wanted to store entities metadata in Glue tables.
